# PHP doesn't display any error

Tags: php

I don't get any PHP error, just get a white page on Firefox, and

> Server error
>   The website encountered an error while retrieving http://example.com/pruebas/prov.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly

on Chrome.

This is the code:

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
echo "hola"
echo "hola2";
```

I intentionally made mistake in the `echo "hola"` (there's no ';').

I also tried adding to the end of my .htaccess file -> `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html` replacing username with my current username, and then I created a php.ini in public_html with `"display_errors = on;"`. But I'm still not able to get any PHP error.

Comment: You might be interested to know there's a function that can trigger a Fatal Error instead of leaving off the semicolon: [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: can you access the main php.ini for example mine is located in /etc/php5/apache2/ on my ubuntu machine.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `display_errors` is set to `on` on your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 3):

Your script is dying due to the syntax error before it ever executes, so the `ini_set()` call is never executed and never takes effect. You'd have to change the setting in the appropriate php.ini.

The actual error message may be in a log file somewhere. Try Apache's error_log, or see if PHP's logging somewhere else.

Comment: This happens on a web hosting. Theres a error_log on /public_html but i have no content

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you also have the appropriate `error_reporting` ini value set as well. You can find more information on [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

> Set the error reporting level. The parameter is either an integer representing a bit field, or named constants. The error_reporting levels and constants are described in Predefined Constants, and in php.ini. To set at runtime, use the error_reporting() function. See also the display_errors directive.
>
> In PHP 4 and PHP 5 the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. **This setting does not show E_NOTICE level errors**. You may want to show them during development.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
echo "hola"
echo "hola2";